AccessDeniedHandler not called when using AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer
My application is a simple resource server — I am using AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer() to validate the given access token. The specific documentation I have followed can be found here.
Goal: Return a custom error message when a malformed token (e.g., '123') is given. It does not seem that my accessDeniedHandler is being called. In contrast, when I don't specify a JWT at all, it works fine and a custom error message is returned (authenticationEntryPoint is called).
This is the code I am using (I have modified Microsoft's example as it was using deprecated methods):
@Autowired
private ErrorHandler errorHandler;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrfCustomizer -> csrfCustomizer.disable())
    .with(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer
        .aadResourceServer(), Customizer.withDefaults())
    .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
        .requestsMatchers(antMatcher("/users/**")).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin")).hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE)    
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingCustomizer -> exceptionHandlingCustomizer.authenticationEntryPoint(errorHandler))
    .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingCustomizer -> exceptionHandlingCustomizer.accessDeniedHandler(errorHandler))
    .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagementCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(sessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)));

    return http.build();
}

The specific error handler (simplified):
@Configuration
public class ErrorHandler authenticationEntryPoint, AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void commence() {
        // this is called
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() {
        // this is not called
    }
}

In contrast, this configuration works fine and a custom error message is returned when I provide a malformed token, but I'm not utilising AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer():
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrfCustomizer -> csrfCustomizer.disable())
    .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer
        .authenticationEntryPoint(errorHandler)
        .accessDeniedHandler(errorHandler)
    )
    .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
        .requestsMatchers(antMatcher("/users/**")).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin")).hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE)    
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagementCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(sessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)));

    return http.build();
}

Is there a way to utilise AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer() with both the authenticationEntryPoint and accessDeniedHandler exception handlers?


but I'm not utilising AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer()

I would not set using AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer as a requirement.
Microsoft proprietary Boot starters are randomly maintained and documented. It sometimes took a while before they published versions compatible with new Spring Security versions, and it's not always quite clear what versions a documentation page / starter lib is compatible with. For this reasons, I prefer to use just Spring Boot official starters (spring-boot-stater-client or spring-boot-stater-resource-server), optionaly with an additional starter of mine which is compatible with any OIDC authorization server (AAD, as well as Keycloak, Auth0, Amazon Cognito,...)
So, your second conf is a better starting point. "My" Boot starter can help replace Java security conf with just application properties (and implement rather tricky features like cookie-based CSRF protection, authorities mapping, multi-tenancy, changing authorization code flow redirection statuses, and more).
P.S.
401 is what a resource server should return in case of a missing or invalid token (expired, wrong issuer or audience, etc.). So ensure that you change no more than the error message.

Thank you so much for your thorough answer! I agree with the 401 — I just want to customize the response body which I have difficulty doing at this moment using the first configuration. Any idea how I can do this using the first example if possible at all?

Also, you're right as I see that internally AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer is using oauth2ResourceServer().jwt(). I suppose my main concern is the "magic" that goes behind all of this. In my second configuration, I have absolutely no idea how this jwt token is validated to be honest. I have bookmarked your starter. How did you know about the starters being randomly maintained and documented?!  Frankly, your comment about using the second conf as starting point relieved me a bit!

It is the different issues I had with the various proprietary starters (all doing about the same thing in the end: configuring Spring Security for OpenID) that decided me to write my own.

I the same repo as the starter, I maintain tutorials, some of which dedicated to configuring Spring Security yourself, (without my starter)

For the security have you missed ?
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity

On your configuration class
I've found this 'tuto' https://gpiskas.com/posts/refresh-oauth2-tokens-spring-boot-spring-cloud-azure/ and both yours and this one uses these annotations.
For the exception part you can use a more global exception handler
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
class CustomExceptionHandler(){

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    CustomErrorObj customExceptionHandling(e: CustomException) {
        return new CustomErrorObj(e.class.getName()+": "+e.getMessage())
    }

}


Thank you for your help. The article you've referenced is something I had indeed also found, but unfortunately didn't help as it still didn't trigger my access denied handler. I have tried your ControllerAdvice example (not in this way but trying to handle the AccessDeniedException itself). This didn't work — and I believe that your example will catch all sorts of exceptions — this is something I haven't tried yet. Will get back to you on this one asap!
